# Python pandas : add one hour to a Dataframe column containing dates

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timedelta

I am new at python.
I have a df called dates which is storing dates. I want to add an extra hour to the whole column.

```
0       2011-01-07
1       2011-01-07
2       2011-01-10
3       2011-01-10
4       2011-01-10
Name: dates, Length: 15644, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This is the code I want to apply on it

```
from datetime import datetime , timedelta

timestamp = pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 12:00')
new_timestamp = timestamp + timedelta(days=0, hours=1)
```

The code works fine on its own but how can I apply these functions on my df which is stored as a pandas series?

Please help.
Thanks!!!

Comment: You can improve your post by [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it using the Markdown syntax.

Comment: Do you want to add a column showing hours?

Comment: Try using [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to, given a certain column filled with dates, add an hour to each observation.

With `timedelta` and a `lambda` function you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

dates = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['2011-01-07', '2011-01-07', '2011-01-10', '2011-01-10', '2011-01-10']})
dates['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dates['dates'])

# Add Hours to the format
dates['dates'] = dates['dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

print(dates.head().to_markdown())

Result:

```
|    | dates         |
|---:|:--------------|
|  0 | 2011-01-07 00 |
|  1 | 2011-01-07 00 |
|  2 | 2011-01-10 00 |
|  3 | 2011-01-10 00 |
|  4 | 2011-01-10 00 |
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help. Your method is correct  The problem though is that  timedelta(hours =1) overrides the time to 01:00:00. I want to add an hour to the timestamp not set the hour to  01:00:00 . I hope I am making myself clear this time.

Comment: Se you want to change the format of the date, am I right?
From: `2011-01-07` to `2011-01-07 01`

Comment: I've already changed the answer, take a look at it :)

Comment: you could simply do `df["dates"] += pd.Timedelta(hours=1)`, no need for lambda or vanilla Python timedelta

Comment: @nauelserraino.First I want to add the current time to the dates column , so dates become timestamps. After that I want to add three hours to the timestamp .